# MEAN Stack routing issue, angular routing does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I have my routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
//I can't use this because angular routing does not work
/*app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
});*/
    app.get('/submit', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/submit.html');
    }); 

    app.get('/schedule', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/schedule.html');
    }); 

    app.get('/requests', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/requests.html');
    });

    app.get('/tv_left', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/tv_left.html');
    });

    app.get('/tv_center', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/tv_center.html');
    });

    app.get('/tv_right', function(req,res){
        res.sendfile('./public/tv_right.html');
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
    });
};
```

and my appRoutes.js like this

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })

        .when('/submit', {
            templateUrl: 'submit.html',
            controller: 'SubmitController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

basicly if I use app.get('*'), then any request will go back to index.html, eventhough the url changed.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please elaborate a bit more on the core issue as to what is not working

Comment: be a lot smarter to use asset directories then route anyhting that isn't a directory to index

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because express handles routes in the order they are defined. If you want index.html as a catch-all route, move it to the bottom of the function.

Further reading: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/10/express-js-middleware-demystified/